# transparent iframe on top of the document prevents mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm inserting iframe on top of the webpage. iframe with 100vw 100vh, z-index: 999, position: fixed.
This iframe is transparent but it contains some div elements which are not transparent(some kind of controls)

**The problem:**
When I set iframe pointer-events to none and set iframe child elements(controls div) pointer events to auto child elements do not react to my mouse clicks. (why it is like this?)
If I will not set iframe pointer events to none then content of webpage below iframe will not be accessible.

Comment: if it is a third party iFrame then your CSS or click events will not work inside it.

Comment: It will be easier to look into this if you could put up a short runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem.